# monkeyrunner problem. java.lang.ClassCastException: when use sameAs() method

Tags: monkeyrunner

I build SDK from source code.
And I want to use the following script:

```
img=MonkeyRunner.loadImageFromFile(path='/home/alsu/monkeyrunner/device.png')
img_1=device.takeSnapshot()

img_1.sameAs(img, 1)
```

But this error occurs:

```
File "/home/semc/monkey/out/host/linux-x86/sdk/android-sdk_eng.semc_linux-x86/tools/test.py", line 23, in <module>
    if img_1.sameAs(img,1):
    at com.android.monkeyrunner.MonkeyImage.sameAs(MonkeyImage.java:138)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)

java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.ClassCastException: org.python.core.PySingleton cannot be cast to com.android.monkeyrunner.core.IMonkeyImage
```

Please help.

Comment: What if you run your script with monkeyrunner found in Android SDK ?

Comment: I'm getting the same error using monkeyrunner in SDKTools Revision 12. Before the call I print each object and they each identify as MonkeyImages.

Answer (score 3):

MonkeyImage.sameAs() is just broken -- it doesn't matter what you pass to it, you'll get that error.

**Workaround: use convertToBytes():**

```
new_snap = device.takeSnapshot()
old_snap = MonkeyRunner.loadImageFromFile(control_dir + '/' + test_name + '.png')
#if new_snap.sameAs(old_snap) == True:
new_bytes = new_snap.convertToBytes('png')
old_bytes = old_snap.convertToBytes('png')
if new_bytes == old_bytes:
    print 'Test ' + test_name + ' PASSED'
else:
    print 'Test ' + test_name + ' FAILED'
```

**Update: Oct 27, 2011: comparing portion of snapshot**

As per kaciula's comment, this is the code to remove the status bar from the snapshot:

```
device = MonkeyRunner.waitForConnection(emulator)
width = int(device.getProperty('display.width'))
height = int(device.getProperty('display.height'))
density = device.getProperty('display.density')
if density == .75:
    density_dir = 'ldpi'
    snap_rect = 0, 19, width, height - 19
elif density == 1.5:
    density_dir = 'hdpi'
    snap_rect = 0, 38, width, height - 38
elif density == 2.0:
    density_dir = 'xhdpi'
    snap_rect = 0, 50, width, height - 50
else:
    density_dir = 'mdpi'
    snap_rect = 0, 25, width, height - 25
new_snap = device.takeSnapshot()
new_snap = new_snap.getSubImage(snap_rect)
```

Comment: The 2 screenshots are very rarely identical. For example, the clock values change. Do you have any idea on how we can use this workaround with a similarity percent?

Comment: @kaciula Added code to remove the status bar. Vote it up and tell your friends. :-)

Answer (score 1):

Had the same problem with SDKTools Revision 12.

Update to SDKTools Revision 15 solved the issue for me.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for the issue.  This change should fix the problem:

https://review.source.android.com/#/c/25618/

Comment: Please post more than just a link. Links tend to disappear, questions don't.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problem elsewhere. Instead of img_1.sameAs(img, 1) try img_1.sameAs(img, 1.0). The sameAs() function takes float value. It shouldn't matter since it is python... but it is Jython - everything the worst of python and java in one place ;-)

Answer (score 0):

`sameAs` works just fine until you move the image file to a different folder and load it again. Strange bug...

**Later edit:**
I think I got to the bottom of this. The problem seems to be that `MonkeyRunner.loadImageFromFile()` is not giving an error when the file name is not a valid one.

For example, something like `MonkeyRunner.loadImageFromFile("d:\p.png")` will work just fine, but something like `MonkeyRunner.loadImageFromFile("d:\t.png")` will not work. The reason is quite simple: `\t` is a special sequence.

The solution is to use `\\\` or `/` as folder separators.

Answer (score 0):

I was also confronted with a similar problem when I used `sameAs()`. My problem is caused by three reasons:

1. Two images are of different resolutions, so the `sameAs` function breaks at runtime.
2. The images path is wrong. Even though I used the wrong path, `loadImageFromFile()` never mentions it to us. So we should determine whether this path is correct or not.
3. Poor SDK version. In my case, I used SDK_r23.